# what are basic functionality of operator?

Tags: java

hi, 
can anyone tell me what ":"  operator does and please explain the below condition statement?

for(String key:keyset)
    -----> what : operator  does

Comment: google for `enhanced for loop`.

Comment: https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the Java for each loop work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work)

Comment: Does not show any research at all.

Answer (score 3):

It's not an operator, it's just part of the syntax. What you see is the enhanced for loop or for-each loop. It iterates over `keyset` and binds each string it contains to the variable `key` one after another in each iteration.